# Varying the action with respect to vanishing metric component in conformal gauge

Tags: general-relativity, action, variational-calculus

Consider the action

\begin{equation}
I=\int d^2x\sqrt{-h}\left(\Phi^2R +\lambda(\partial\Phi)^2-U(\Phi)\right)
\end{equation}
Let us suppose that the metric is in conformal gauge

\begin{equation}
ds^2=e^{2\omega(u^+,u^-)}du^+du^-
\end{equation}

This paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482 computes at page 8 the equation of motion for the metric component $h^{++}$. The answer is
\begin{equation}
-e^{2\omega}\partial_+(e^{-2\omega}\partial_+\Phi^2)=T_{++}
\end{equation}
How can this equation be derived?

The problem is that the metric component is zero. The only thing that I could do until now is to write the action in term of $\omega$.
For example, the Ricci curvature is $R=-4e^{-2\omega}\partial_+\partial_-\omega$ and $\sqrt{-h}=e^{2\omega}$. I could vary the action with respect to $\omega$, but I do not get the equation of the paper.

The variation of the action with respcet to a generic $h$ just gives the Einstein equations...and after that I choose the ++ component, each term of the left hand side is zero...

Comment: Hi Akhi. Please don't make trivial edits to bump the question to the front page; if someone knows the answer, they'll get round to answering it.

Comment: Have you tried deriving the standard field equations from the metric variation and just inspecting the $++$ component equation?

Comment: But the variation just gives  the Einstein equations...and each term of the left hand side is zero